# Is a perspective projection a Möbius transformation?

Tags: projective-geometry, mobius-transformation

Both perspective projection and Möbius transformations exhibit cross-ratio invariance, but can a perspective projection be defined as a subgroup of the Möbius group? In other words, is a perspective projection a Möbius transformation?

Comment: Möbius transformations are bijective. Projections are not

Comment: By "projection", do you mean a perspective projection specifically? Because a complex mapping can be considered a Möbius transformation if and only if it can be obtained by a stereographic projection from the complex plane onto an admissible sphere in R3. http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~arnold/papers/moebius.pdf